# Why were Logical Operators created?

Tags: programming-languages, logical-operators, language-design

Almost all programming languages are having the concept of logical operator
I am having a query why logical operators were created.  I googled and found its created for condition based operation, but that's a kind of usage i think.

I am interested in the answer that what are the challenges people faced without this operator. Please explain with example if possible.

Comment: This is kind of vague. You want to know why they were created, even though you found what their usage is?

Comment: Assembly / cpu hardware *doesn't* have logical operators, so [tag:cpu-architecture] doesn't really apply. This is a high-level language design question.  (I'm assuming you're talking about short-circuit evaluation operators like C's `a && b` which treats both sides as boolean, not bitwise-and `a & b`.)  Can you explain what the CPU-architecture aspect of this question is, and why you added that tag?

Comment: There are no challenges to face. They are for convenience only. Alan Turing showed they are not needed with his single instruction: `copy, minus, branch on negative`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am interested in the answer that what are the challenges people faced without this operator.

Super-verbose deeply nested `if()` conditions, and especially loop conditions.

```
while (a && b) {
    a = something;
    b = something_else;
}
```

written without logical operators becomes:

```
while (a) {
    if (!b) break;   // or if(b){} else break;  if you want to avoid logical ! as well
    a = something;
    b = something_else;
}
```

Of if you don't want a loop, do you want to write this?

```
if (c >= 'a') {
    if (c <= 'z') {
        stuff;
    }
}
```

No, of course you don't because it's horrible compared to `if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')`, especially if there's an `else`, or this is inside another nesting.  Especially if your coding-style rules require 8-space indentation for each level of nesting, or the `{` on its own line making each level of nesting eat up even more vertical space.

---

**Note that `a&b` is *not* equivalent to `a&&b`: even apart from short-circuit evaluation**.  (Where `b` isn't even evaluated if `a` is false.)  e.g. `2 & 1` is false, because their integer bit patterns don't have any of the same bits set.

Short-circuit evaluation allows loop conditions like `while(p && p->data != 0)` to check for a NULL pointer and then conditionally do something only on non-NULL.

Compact expressions were a big deal when computers were programmed over slow serial lines using paper teletypes.

---

Also note that these are purely *high*-level language-design considerations.  CPU hardware doesn't have anything like logical operators; it usually takes multiple instructions to implement a `!` on an integer (into a 0/1 integer, not when used as an if condition).

`if (a && b)` typically compiles to two test/branch instructions in a row.